# Inserting data into a MS Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
try
{
    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\HP8200\\Desktop\\ELISA2014Data.mdb ;Persist Security Info=False;");
    myConnection.Open();

    // Create Oledb command to execute particular query
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

    // Query to create table with specified data columne
    myCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE UXZona([IDZona] int, [Morada] text)";
    //myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Tabela criada");
}
catch
{
    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\HP8200\\Desktop\\ELISA2014Data.mdb ;Persist Security Info=False;");
    myConnection.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UXZona (IDZona, Morada) VALUES ('" + 
                      transaction.UnloadPlaceAddress.AddressID + "','" + 
                      transaction.UnloadPlaceAddress.AddressLine2 + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Dados inseridos");
}
```

I need to insert data into the database but it isn't working. I launch the program and there are no errors, I do everything but when I check the database the table is empty.

UPDATE

Now when i launch the program I have this error:

"System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized." on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **never EVER** concatenate together your SQL statements - ***ALWAYS*** use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @marc_s I will have that in mind, thanks

Comment: @marc_s just one question, I am using access, how does that SQL Injection alert affects me?

Comment: Why do you put the INSERT-part in the catch block? It's never executed if no error occurs.

Comment: @MatSnow I've tested on try{} and on catch{} and doesnt work on both

Comment: You're using **SQL** to talk to MS Access - so therefore you're *potentially vulnerable* to SQL injection .....

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things wrong!  I give below corrected code:

```
try
{
    bool success = false;
    using (var myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\HP8200\\Desktop\\ELISA2014Data.mdb ;Persist Security Info=False;"))
    {
        // Create Oledb command to execute particular query
        using (var myCommand = new OleDbCommand())
        { 
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

            // Query to create table with specified data columne
            //myCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE UXZona([IDZona] int, [Morada] text)";
            //myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //MessageBox.Show("Tabela criada");

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UXZona (IDZona, Morada) VALUES (@id, @morada)"; 
            var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@id";
            param.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
            param.Value = transaction.UnloadPlaceAddress.AddressID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            param = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@morada";
            param.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
            param.Value = transaction.UnloadPlaceAddress.AddressLine2;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            myConnection.Open();

            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (success)
    {       
        MessageBox.Show("Dados inseridos");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

By way of explanation.  I have commented out (but not deleted) all references to creating the table.  Table creation and table insertion should be in two different routines.  Normally you only create a table once, but insert is probably called many times.

I have placed the OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand within using loops.  This is good practice, as they both implement IDisposable.  Writing your code like this means that the Garbage Collector (GC) knows immediately that it can safely dispose of the objects after use.

I have changed the insert statement such that it takes parameters.  This is highly recommended practice to safeguard against SQL Injection (if you do not know what this is please Google it).  In fact Access is relatively immune from the worst forms of SQL Injection, because it rejects any command that contains multiple statements, but please get into good habits.  With time you will progress to other databases which do not have this restriction.

I deliberately wait before opening the connection until just before it is needed.  Connections consume resources, so it is good practice to use them as sparingly as possible.  Also for this reason, I have moved your success message outside of the using loops.  This means that the cleanup of resources is not waiting for the user to click OK in the message box.

Finally try catch is all well and good, but normally you want to know why the error occurred.  Hence you add (Exception ex) to catch so that you can find the reason.

PS What I forgot to mention.  In your original INSERT, you were surrounding both VALUES with single quotes.  Only use single quotes for strings/text.  Integers and other numbers require no quotes.  If you quote them, the database will treat it as a string and you will get a data type error.